# Opencart URL Redirect from Module Blog to Information page

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, opencart, opencart-module

I'm trying to redirect Opencart Blog module page's to Information page via .htaccess

Im using opencart version 1.5.2.1 with installed blog module

here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
Redirect 301 /blog/blog-page.html /Information-article
```

When I open, `example.com/blog/blog-page.html` I have redirected to this URL:

`example.com/Information-article?_route_=blog/blog-page.html`

whitch is showing original `/blog/blog-page.html` content, not `/Information-article` what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect 301 /blog/blog-page.html /Information-article
 try putting this on top of rewrite rules